# Gitlab - Update version package

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We created a vuejs library proyect in Gitlab and created a simple pipelines that excecuted after when we pushed the commit.

We have a problem when last job execute the `npm version patch` (that update the patch in the project) but... it's not updated and it's doesn't work.

.gutlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:8.10.0-slim

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run peers:add && npm run test:unit
  tags:
    - docker

lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - npm run lint
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/

publish:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm run peers:remove
    - echo -e "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my-project>/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_NPM_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc
    - npm login
    - npm version patch
    - npm publish
```

And package.json

```
[...]
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build:dev": "npm run clean && webpack --config build/webpack.config.dev.js",
    "version": "npm run build:dev && git add -A dist",
    "postversion": "git push --follow-tags"
    ...
}
[...]
```

Jobs lint and test working but the publish not.

```
[...]
removed 4 packages in 9.428s
$ echo -e "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my-project>/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_NPM_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc
$ npm login
Username: npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/...-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

We need when the Merge Request it's accepted, automatically builed library and upload to npm repository with a new version (new patch, `npm version patch`). It's possible?

Thx.

Comment: if it is possible in shell it is also possible in CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm login` is an interactive command so doesn't work in CI very well. Try using the package [`npm-login-noninteractive`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-login-noninteractive) to pass your credentials via command line.  You can install it globally in your before_script:

```
before_script:
  - npm i -g npm-login-noninteractive
```

Then call it in place of `npm login` in your publish script.